# How to compare two columns in MS excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have two columns of data in excel sheet- column A and column B. I want that the values which are in column a but not in column b, should appear column c. for example please look at this screen shoot-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0K9a.jpg

THANK YOU VERY MUCH..

Comment: Post your code and not an image of it.

Comment: @Fred -ii- As you can see in the image that there are few values in column a and the same values are in column b also (except 400). Only 500, 800 and 400 are those three values (see in red) which are not in column b. I applied this formula in column c-                                                                              =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1;$B$1:$B$10;1;FALSE));A1;"")                                  but it is showing 400 only in column c. On the other hand I want that it should show 800 and 500 and 400 in column c. I think that I have to use arrary formula in column c. Please help me.

Comment: There was an answer (now deleted) that contained the following link https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/08/26/excel-compare-two-columns-matches-differences/ and am not sure if you did have a look at it. You should post your formula in your question also; this will make it easier for others to help you out if I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this array formula in C2(it must be in C2 or the reference of $C$1:C1 must be changed to the cell directly above the first instance of this formula):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,$A$1:$A$10)<>COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6,$A$1:$A$10))*(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$1:$A$9)<COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,$A$1:$A$10)-COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6,$A$1:$A$10)),0)),"")
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then copy/drag the formula down till you get blanks.

[image]

Comment: Dear @Scott Craner the codes suggested by you are not working. i used thsese codes in c2 as array formula- =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$9,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,$A$1:$A$9)<>COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6,$A$1:$A$9))*(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$1:$A$9)=0),0)),"") but it is showing only 800 in all cells of column c. please look at this snapshoot- http://imgur.com/a/6kTTY

Comment: You entered the formula into all the cells at once.  you need to enter the formula into C2 only, press Ctrl-Shift-Enter, then copy and paste down as I instructed above.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear @Scott Craner  now the formula is working almost fine. But still there is problem. As i added three times 100s in column a which are not in column b but the in column c there is only one 100. please look at this snapshoot- http://imgur.com/a/rBMxz                                          PLEASE HELP. THANKS..

Comment: Thanks dear @Scott Craner  you are really awesome at excel. Sir there is one more problem. In fact the formula is working fine, but sir it is also slowing down the speed of excel sheet. I mean to say, i applied this formula in a wide range. So when i enter any value then it shows calculating or processing at the lower penal of excel sheet and the system hangs down. i think the formula is very long and it has to do so many calculations that's why it is slowing down. Could you please provide me small formula for this purpose. please look at this screen shoot-    http://imgur.com/9eM3nAz

Comment: @user3906491 this is an array formula, It will slow down the calc times, the only way around that is to use vba with virtual arrays.